# what is the utility of the buildroot on beagleboneBlack?

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard, buildroot

I don't understand what is the reason of buildroot of a card such as beaglebone black where as it has a Linux system when we bought.What is the utility of the buildroot?

Answer (score 3):

Build a completely custom, lightweight, and fast-booting embedded Linux system?

Comment: My question is the beaglebone black  does not have a Linux system installed on it?if yes why we make buildroot?for what reason??

Comment: @arrowman, just as Thomas wrote, to create a custom and ligthweight linux system. (Fast-booting is more or less a side effect of that, at least until you need to really trim to boot speed).
Everyone doesn't want / need a full desktop linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Buildroot** is a set of `Makefiles` and patches that makes it easy to generate a **complete embedded Linux system**.

Buildroot can generate any or all of a cross-compilation toolchain, a root filesystem, a kernel image and a bootloader image.

It is useful mainly for people working with small or embedded systems, using various CPU architectures (x86, ARM, MIPS, PowerPC, etc.) : it automates the building process of your embedded system and eases the cross-compilation process.

The resulting **root filesystem** is mounted `read-only`, but other filesystems can be mounted `read/write` for persistence.

Although user accounts can be created, in practice almost everything is done as root. **Buildroot uses no package manager**.

Instead, package selection is managed through `make menuconfig`.

source http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Operating_Systems